# Combine Excel cells into 1 cell based on date in next column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've exported some log data into a spreadsheet. It's 2 columns:

```
Entry 1 |  29/5/2021
Entry 2 |  29/5/2021
Entry 3 |  28/5/2021
Entry 4 |  28/5/2021
Entry 5 |  28/5/2021
```

i.e. each entry occupies a single cell, with multiple entries over multiple rows per each date.

How do I combine all entries into a single cell on 1 row for each date?

I know this isn't an easy task, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear: Please outline clearer the cells' borders for your data and for the the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Office 365, you can use `TEXTJOIN`, `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions.

Note that I used a **Table** with structured references in the formulas as this makes the references auto-adjust.  You can use regular addressing if you prefer.

eg:

```
J2: =UNIQUE(Table6[Column2])
K2: =TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER(Table6[Column1],J2=Table6[Column2]))
```

Select `K2` and fill down as far as needed

[image]

***Edit:***

If you don't have Office 365, you can obtain your results in Power Query which is available in Windows Excel 2010+

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in the data
//change Table Name in next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Entry", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),

//Group by date and concatenate the Entries
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {
        {"Dates", (t)=> List.Accumulate(t[Entry],"",(state, current)=>
            if state = "" then current else state & ", " & current), type text}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have Excel 2019.

Comment: @Steve I will add a Power Query solution

Comment: Amazing, thank you Ron.

Answer (score 1):

> all entries into a single cell on 1 row for each date
> Assuming the cells of your shared table is `A1:B5`

In C1 put : `=A1`
In C2 put : `=IF(B2=B1,C1&"|"&A2,A2)` and drag downwards.

In D1 put : `=IF(B1=B2,"",B1)` and drag downwards.

In E1 put : `=IF(B1=B2,"",C1)` and drag downwards.

In F1 put : `=ROW()-COUNTBLANK($E$1:E1)` and drag downwards.

In G1 put : `=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(ROW(),F:F,0)),"")` and drag downwards.

In H1 put : `=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(ROW(),F:F,0)),"")` and drag downwards.

That shall give you the combined cells per different date.

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Comment: Thanks. It's the last step `In D1 put : =IF(B1=B2,"",C2) and drag downwards.` that doesn't seem to work. It takes the first entry for tomorrows date, and places it in the last cell for today's date, in column D.

Comment: My bad, Thanks for the heads up. [Solution updated].  The logic behind : "String combine" (in Column C), 'selective' printout (in column D&E), non-blank row count (Column F) & combined printout (Column H&I). | If you r stuck at it feel free to ask. /(^_^)

Answer (score 1):

Copy Column B to the New Column and go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates**:
[image]

Then run this array formula end with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B1:B5=E1,A1:A5,""))
```

[image]

Comment: `Shift+Alt+Enter` didn't do anything, unfortunately, I am using Excel 2019.

Comment: Ctrl Shift Enter

Comment: @Steve, I provided the wrong operation, I modified the reply.  You should use **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.